# cannot load such file -- Kconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, operating-system, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm wondering why i got this error on particular situation.

One of my controller class has

```
require 'Kconv'
```

on top.
And after running app by "$ rails s", i got this error (cannot load such file -- Kconv) in only my centos5.10. My mac has no problem with the code and can work correctly.

**Specs**

My mac

- Rails 4.2.0
- ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
- gem 2.2.2
- Yosemite 10.10.2

centos5.10

- Rails 4.2.0
- ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
- gem 2.4.8
- CentOS release 5.10 (Final)

And one of tutorial site mentioned about need to install 'Kconv' by gem.
But both of my pc has error with it.

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'kconv' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: bconv, conv, iconv, sconv
```

My question is why this error happens even if these specs are almost same. Another tutorial site said this lib is included into general package. If so, if i use same ruby version, i don't get this error, do i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the file is `kconv.rb`, not `Kconv.rb`. On your Mac, you are presumably using a case-insensitive file system such as FAT, NTFS or HFS, whereas on your CentOS box, you are using a case-sensitive file system such as ext4, btrfs or ZFS.

So, it should be

```
require 'kconv'
```

and the fact that

```
require 'Kconv'
```

works on a case-insensitive file system is just pure dumb luck.